# Angular 2 Input time doesnt return seconds

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<input class="form-control" type="time" step="1" [(ngModel)]="dateField"  min="00:00:00" max="23:59:59">
```

Thats my code for this input. the problem is after change a time (for example to `07:00:00`) the variable into ngModel have only a `07:00`. So the problem occur when the seconds are 00 only. Is that possible to return full time with hours,minutes and seconds always not only in case when seconds are higher than 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the `dateField` use this code to get seconds too:

```
this.dateField = this.dateField && this.dateField.length === 5 ? this.dateField + ":00" : this.dateField;
```

It appends `:00` if string length is 5 eg: `07:00` turns into `07:00:00`.